# Laravel Sentry 2: Password Bug?

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

When I create a user with `Sentry::createUser()` or `Sentry::register()` and I pass the password (as shown in https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/register) the password won't be saved. Sentry will create the user but the password table attribute is empty.

Why? I know a workaround is to create the user, then get it from the DB, set the password and save it again, but I don't like to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a bug, because your php version is too old.

Like described here https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/98 Sentry checks the computed hashed password. Because of your old php version (<=5.3.7) Sentry uses bcrypt instead of DES.
Sentry doesn't support bcrpyt anymore so you got an exception. Of course the exception is a bit confusing, but you can simply fix this issue. 
Just upgrade your php version at least to 5.4 and it should work.